# Oflline access to note/task/calendar apps

Tags: offline, notes, evernote

Sure Evernote is great, but I don't like the idea of paying for accessing my own data when I am offline, which is still very often the case for tablets when you travel.

Unfortunately, when you read reviews, this bit of information is lacking.

Do you know of any free evernote-like app where synced data can be later accessed offline still for free?

What about Springpad in this regard?